# Mysql Duplicate Entry Error On Insert

Tags: php, mysql, duplicates

Something very bizare is happening right now and I don't understand how to fix it... Well, temporarily I do but the solution I found is not how the program should behave...

So I have this employeetimesheets table:

```
empsheet_id | employee_id |timesheet_status |last_update |isWeekNumber|total_hours|isMonth|isYear|overtimeHours
```

**the variables:**

```
    $isWeekNumber =  $_POST['isWeekNumber'];
    $attendanceyear= $_POST['attendanceyear'];
    $attendancemonth= $_POST['attendancemonth'];
    $employee_id=  $_POST['employee_id'];
```

**the query:**

```
    $insertemptime= $db->prepare("INSERT INTO employeetimesheets (employee_id,isWeekNumber,isMonth,isYear) VALUES (?,?,?,?)");
    $insertemptime->bind_param("iiss",$employee_id,$isWeekNumber,$attendancemonth,$attendanceyear);
    $insertemptime->execute() or die(mysqli_error($db)); 
    $insertemptime->close();
```

**On insert NEW row I receive this error when there is already a row with same `employee_id`**

> Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'mysqli_sql_exception' with message
>   'Duplicate entry '6748372' for key 'EmployeeTimeSheetsKey''

If I delete the row with the `employee_id` I'm trying to insert, the query works. I"m confused because it's an insert statement... I should be able to add as many rows I want with the same `employee_id`, yes? Anybody has an idea what's going on?

Comment: `Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'mysqli_sql_exception' with message 'Duplicate entry '6748372' for key 'EmployeeTimeSheetsKey''` You are getting this message because you have already an entry with`6748372` id in your mysql table

Comment: @SahilGulati: I know this is why i'm confused.

Comment: For that you have to do two things i am updating my post for that

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You've set the field employee_id  to unique instead of index

Remove unique index from field and add index again without unique

Example sql code

1. Check index

   ```
   SHOW INDEX FROM employeetimesheets;
   ```
2. Remove Index

   ```
   ALTER TABLE employeetimesheets DROP INDEX employee_id;
   ```
3. Add Index

   ```
   CREATE INDEX employeetimesheets ON employee_id;
   ```